# Eclipse Oxygen android false missing dx.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I just tried to install Android SDK into Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) and I just generate the first Android project... "Hello world".

I connect my device, try to run it...and Eclipse show me into the console
"Failed to load C:\Users\Luca Lombardi\android-sdks\build-tools\27.0.0\lib\dx.jar"
"Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!"

I checked into this folder, but the **dx.jar** already existes into this folder!
I already tried to:

- Clear the cache and reloaded the package
- Tried to install again the Android SDK
- Copy the **dx.jar** into the folder

But nothing has work properly.

Have someone some ideas in order to fix this problem?
I don't beleive that is so difficult start to develop on android...

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me, I also installed the latest Android SDK Build-tools(V 27.0.0), now I have changed to old Android SDK Build-tools(V 25.0.3). now it is fine for me.

new path:android-sdks\build-tools\25.0.3\lib